# How to use jqueryrain menu?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to add this menu http://jqueryrain.com/tutorial/menu/demo7/ to my project, but when the cursor is not over the circle the li items are disappeared.
In addition to this I removed some icons, so I have only 4 li items.How can I arrange them so that they will be symetric relatively to the circle. 
I will appreciate your help.
Thanks
Here is the picture:
[menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bq7Hs.png)

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help _("why isn't this code working?")_ must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I wrote what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to change the value of the rotation.

```css
.demo{
    background: #99b977;
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
.navbar{
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    line-height: 150px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #fff;
    margin: 70px auto;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 2.75em;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #99b977;
    transition: 0.24s 0.2s;
}
.navbar:hover{
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
}
.navbar .menu{
    list-style: none;
    padding: 10;
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: -75px;
    left: -75px;
    border: 150px solid transparent;
    cursor: default;
    border-radius: 50%;
    transform: scale(0);
    transition: transform 1.4s 0.07s;
    z-index: -1;
}
.navbar:hover .menu{
    transition: transform 0.4s 0.08s, z-index   0s  0.5s;
    transform: scale(1);
    z-index: 1;
}
.navbar .menu li{
    position: absolute;
    top: -100px;
    left: -100px;
    transform-origin: 100px 100px;
    transition: all 0.5s 0.1s;
}
.navbar:hover .menu li{
    transition: all 0.6s;
}
.navbar .menu li a{
    width: 45px;
    height: 45px;
    line-height: 45px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 60%;
    color: #99b977;
    transition: 0.6s;
}
.navbar:hover .menu li:nth-child(1){
    transition-delay: 0.02s;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.navbar:hover .menu li:nth-child(1) a{
    transition-delay: 0.04s;
    transform: rotate(315deg);
}
.navbar:hover .menu li:nth-child(2){
    transition-delay: 0.04s;
    transform: rotate(125deg);
}
.navbar:hover .menu li:nth-child(2) a{
    transition-delay: 0.08s;
    transform: rotate(595deg);
}
.navbar:hover .menu li:nth-child(3){
    transition-delay: 0.06s;
    transform: rotate(165deg);
}
.navbar:hover .menu li:nth-child(3) a{
    transition-delay: 0.12s;
    transform: rotate(555deg);
}
.navbar:hover .menu li:nth-child(4){
    transition-delay: 0.08s;
    transform: rotate(205deg);
}
.navbar:hover .menu li:nth-child(4) a{
    transition-delay: 0.16s;
    transform: rotate(515deg);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Menu Style : Demo 7</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="demo">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="navbar">MENU
                        <ul class="menu">
                            <li><a href="#" class="fa fa-facebook"></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" class="fa fa-google-plus"></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" class="fa fa-twitter"></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" class="fa fa-linkedin"></a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

With the facebook icon, I changed the rotation value for the li.

```
.navbar:hover .menu li:nth-child(1){
    transition-delay: 0.02s;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

Once you have change this value, you have to change the the rotation value for the icon

```
.navbar:hover .menu li:nth-child(1) a{
    transition-delay: 0.04s;
    transform: rotate(315deg);
}
```

I let you finish.

Comment: Ok.In addition to this, how can I prevent from the icons to disappear when the mouse is not over them?

Comment: If I understand you, you don't want the animation when you go over the circle ?
If so, you don't need the hover in your css when you pass through the menu